# Netty-based application with long calculations

Tags: playframework, netty

I am going to start developing an application where the network subsystem will be based on Netty. There is not much documentation for it, especially it is hard to find some "good practices".

So the question is: In a Netty-based application where should I should perform long calculations?

For example let it be a very slow calculator which will calculate the factorial of some integer in one minute. In Netty I'll have FrameDecoder which converts raw data to packets, and PacketProcessor selecting operations to perform. And now its time to perform numeric operation itself.. 
So the question is: which is the typical way of doing long calculations with Netty?

I know, Play Framework 2 uses Akka actors, but how are they connected?

Comment: If you already have Akka I suggest using Remote Actors: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/remoting.html

Answer (score 0):

You usually have either an async way of doing the calculation and so free up the io-thread (not block it) or you use a ExecutionHandler which will take care of moving the processing out of the io-thread for you.